# Forbid buffer content to save to old file when buffer file name is changed

Tags: emacs

I have follow use case annoying me a lot.

1. Open file `foo.rb` in emacs buffer.
2. rename `foo.rb` to `bar.rb` use external tool.(e.g. rename from terminal)
3. Select `foo.rb` buffer in Emacs, edit it, when `C-x s` to save, this buffer
   save as old file name (`foo.rb`), not expected `bar.rb`.

Is there any emacs config to prevent this??

What i expect is some like:

1. open file `foo.rb` in Emacs buffer.
2. rename `foo.rb` to `bar.rb` use external tool
3. edit `foo.rb` buffer, when save, told me: file is removed, or prompt, 
   save as a new file name.

Comment: If you rename the file using [`dired`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html), it renames and redirects the buffer(s) automatically. Try it!

Comment: I know dired can do this, and i know others emacs package can do this more well, but, often, file name is changed by a `external tool`, as i say in my question.

Comment: This is my point -- do _not_ use external tools when editing a file in emacs, use emacs for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the beginning of a solution.  The devil's in the details; there are probably a lot of corner cases that this code doesn't deal with.

```
(defvar do-not-save-list ())

(defun do-not-save-add-to-list (event)
  (when (eq 'renamed (cadr event))
    (add-to-list 'do-not-save-list
                 (caddr event))))

(defun do-not-save-add-watcher ()
  (setq do-not-save-list (remove (buffer-file-name) do-not-save-list))
  (file-notify-add-watch (buffer-file-name)
                         '(change)
                         #'do-not-save-add-to-list))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'do-not-save-add-watcher)

(defun do-not-save-check ()
  (let ((filename (buffer-file-name)))
    (when (member filename do-not-save-list)
      (message "not saving %s" filename)
      t ;; returns non-nil to prevent write
      )))
(add-hook 'write-file-functions #'do-not-save-check)

(defun do-not-save-kill-hook ()
  (setq do-not-save-list (remove (buffer-file-name) do-not-save-list)))
(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook #'do-not-save-kill-hook)
```